# invert binary tree in python with recursion

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I looked into the code of inverting binary tree in the internet. But I couldnt what it is doing. Its written in Python. I am a python programmer myself but couldnt understand it.

The snippet is as follows:

```
def invertTree(root):
    if root:
        root.left, root.right = invertTree(root.right), invertTree(root.left)
        return root
```

I don't understand this `root.left` and `root.right` . Root is the main node in the graph, it will be an integer or a single character. But what does root.left represent in Python? I honestly do not get it.

**Update:**

My understanding is the node is access like below:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, data):
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
      self.data = data
   def PrintTree(self):
      print(self.data)

root = Node(10)
root.PrintTree()
```

Comment: `root` may be a node that has an `int` for its `.value` or whatever the value attribute is called, but it's certainly not an `int` itself - try running `type(root)` and see what its actual type is. My bet it's some sort of `Node()` and what is happening here is that this function simply swaps `.left` and `.right` for the node, and then proceeds to do the same for both subtrees - effectively "inverting" the tree.

Comment: It's unclear. Are you looking at [this](https://favtutor.com/blogs/invert-binary-tree)? The sample code on that article define the Node class and create instances of the Node. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: It's still unclear. Try to understand these concepts: Python class, Python ```__init__```, Python instance variables, instances of the Node, references to the left and right child node, binary tree. It seems that you can't describe what's your problem CLEARLY because you don't understand these concepts.

Comment: Every solution I watched for inverting binary tree, it just 4 lines of code of recursion, but I dont understand what's going under the hood. I thought we have to represent a binary tree first using classes and init function. But in leetcode, there is no any class to represent the node. There is just a class and a function to write the code.

Comment: See my answer. That's the best I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary tree can be used to store elements sorted by a key.(Look for the balanced binary tree for more advanced topic.) If the elements are sorted in ascending order, for any subtree T with the root node R, any element in the left branch of R should be smaller than any element in the right branch of R.

This is a heavily modified version of the example code at [Invert a Binary Tree](https://favtutor.com/blogs/invert-binary-tree) by Shivali Bhadaniya.

```
'''
         5                         5
       /   \                     /   \
      /     \                   /     \           
     3       7    =======>     7       3           
    / \     /                   \     / \
   1   4   6                     6   4   1 
'''
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = self.right = None
        self.data = data
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

def invert(root):
    left, right = root.left, root.right
    print(['visiting', root, 'swapping', left, right])
    root.left, root.right = right, left
    if left: invert(left)
    if right: invert(right)

root = Node(5)
root.left = node3 = Node(3)
root.right = node7 = Node(7)
node3.left = Node(1)
node3.right = Node(4)
node7.left = Node(6)

invert(root)
```

This will output the following.

```
['visiting', 5, 'swapping', 3, 7]
['visiting', 3, 'swapping', 1, 4]
['visiting', 1, 'swapping', None, None]
['visiting', 4, 'swapping', None, None]
['visiting', 7, 'swapping', 6, None]
['visiting', 6, 'swapping', None, None]
```

In the above example, the tree before calling `invert()` was sorted in ascending order. After the call, it will be sorted in descending order. That's why the operation is called 'inversion'.

You can understand why the simple recursion of swaping the left child and the right child results in the inversion, by simulating the above example code with a pencil and paper manually. Compare logs with your calculation.

Comment: Thanks Relent, your answer is much clear than those youtube videos. But one final thing I need to ask you is do we have to take input from user every time for this or send a list? Also in leetcode, that init function inside a different class is commented out, then how come the code runs if the init are commented?? Please let me know.

Comment: Leetcode online judge is not open sourced. AFAIK, they run a submitted code(solution) within their proprietary framework, which should contain the definition of the TreeNode class and tree initialization code.

Answer (score 1):

First understand the problem with a diagram..!

**Q:- Given binary tree you have to convert binary tree into invert binary tree.**
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FvrW.png)

Class TreeNode: **{Initialization of the binary tree}**

The key insight here is to realize that in order to invert a binary tree we only need to **recursively swap the children.** To avoid using a tmp variable, we can do this pythonically by taking advantage of Python's tuple packing and unpacking and do a direct swap:

```
> class TreeNode:
>      def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
>          self.val = val
>          self.left = left
>          self.right = right

> class Solution:
>     def invertTree(self, root):
>         if root:
>             root.left, root.right = self.invertTree(root.right), self.invertTree(root.left)
>         return root
```

**Note that if one of the children is null, the condition if root won't be triggered and the swap in the upper level will still be performed (e.g. node has right child but no left child, assigment will be root.left, root.right = root.right, null).**

**what is root.left doing? Traversing the left subtree of the binary tree**

**what is root.right doing? Traversing the right subtree of the binary tree.**

**Note* You can access values of root by root.val as you can see the class TreeNode. I have stored the value in val**

Also to learn more about the binary trees basic questions you should do.

> (1)Preorder Traversal

> (2)Inorder Traversal

> (3)Postorder Traversal

**Updated Section.!**

Q-: How can the root be accessed from the other class.?

A-: Just call it in the main function..!

**Main Function**

```
> if __name__="__main__":
>     s=input()
>     root=TreeNode(s)   
>     Solution().invertTree(root) 
>     inorderTraversal(root) # You can print in any other traversal also as the testcases requirements
```

For more in detail see the driver code (starting from the 18th line {Below Link}):
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/mirror-tree/1

Comment: I have added my code in the update section. I thought the root node is accessed from the self from init which is under the same class. But you are putting two classes. How can the root be accessed from the other class. I dont understand.

Comment: I have added the main function also in my updated section..! if still you want to understand in deeper like inorderTraversal code or how initialization of binary tree implementing..  you can see the driver code. I have given the link you can just login and code it also for better understanding